# Javascript/jQuery: how to get data value from another class using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried with this code but didn't work with me:

```
var data = document.querySelector;
$( document ) .querySelector('.class2').textContent() {
$('.class1').val('.class2');
});
```

The whole idea is that I want to get data from class2 and replace them in class1 and collect them with the Form inputs.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you're mixing jquery `$()` with javascript `.querySelector`.  And do you want `data-`? or the value? or the text?  In this case creating including HTML may help, along with expected input/output values.  See [mcve].

Comment: Your code *looks like* it should be `$(".class1").val($(".class2").text())` but without HTML/expected values, hard to tell.

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, I use this input code: `{% for line_item in cart.items %} <input type="hidden" name="entry.2105509418" id="class1" value=""> <span class="class2">{{line_item.product.title}}, {{line_item.quantity}} - </span> {% endfor %}` , I want to det data from SPAN class2 and collect them in value of input class1 , any recommendations to make it works even with Javascript or jQuery? thanks in advance

Comment: `id="class1"` / `class="class2"` - that's pretty confusing to use "class1" in an `id=`.   You can edit your question and add that info rather than in a comment.  Also if you have a for loop, then don't use `id=` inside it because IDs must be unique with the document.  Give your hidden input a class.

Comment: Next: how are you triggering your code?  Is there a button in each of your `cart.items`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've edited it and gave the hidden input a class and here's the new code: `{% for line_item in cart.items %}
  <input type="hidden" name="entry.2105509418" class="class1" value="{{line_item.product.title}}, {{line_item.quantity}} -">
  <span class="class2">{{line_item.product.title}}, {{line_item.quantity}} - </span>
{% endfor %}` , now how I can get data from class2 and collect them in value in input class1?

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, please take a look on my new question to understand the issue and can help. Thank you so much
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009705/javascript-jquery-how-to-get-data-value-from-another-class]

Answer (score 2):

You have to select the `class2` element and get its value before setting it to the first one. Also, if you have only one item with `class1` or `class2`, use id's instead.

```
var data = $('#class2').text();
$('#class1').val(data);
```

Hope this helps.

Update:

Assuming what you want is to show an alert if the string is empty and only transfer it it's not, you will have to write your code this way:

```
if(field1 == "") {
   alert('');
} else {
   var data = $('#class2').text();
   $('#class1').val(data);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Romi Halasz, thanks for your answer I think it will work but I don't know I can put your code in this code to collect data in field1:
`if(field1 == ""){
alert('');
var data = $('#class2').text();
$('#class1').val(data);
}`
Is the way that I've used to put your code right? If not can you help me to write it in the right way, thank you so much for your help, I realy appreciate it

Comment: Hi James, I have updated my answer, but it's based on my assumption of what your comment means. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi Romi, unfortunately it's not working by I think your code is right but I'm doing something wrong, so to be in the picture, I use this input code:
`{% for line_item in cart.items %}
  <input type="hidden" name="entry.2105509418" id="class1" value="">
  <span class="class2">{{line_item.product.title}}, {{line_item.quantity}} - </span>
{% endfor %}`
And I use your code like this:
`if(field1 == "") {
   alert('');
} else {
   var data = $('.productdata').text();
   $('#pdata').val(data);
}`
Any recommendations to make it works?

Comment: Well, that is out of the scope of your initial question. You have not mentioned that you use a `for` loop, and regarding the code in the comment, who is `.productdata` and `#pdata` ?

Comment: I've edited it and gave the hidden input a class and here's the new code: `{% for line_item in cart.items %} <input type="hidden" name="entry.2105509418" class="class1" value="{{line_item.product.title}}, {{line_item.quantity}} -"> <span class="class2">{{line_item.product.title}}, {{line_item.quantity}} - </span> {% endfor %}` , now how I can get data from class2 and collect them in value in input class1?

Comment: Please paste the additional code in your initial question and format it accordingly. No one will be able to read, let alone understand what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: `#pdata` is **class1** and `.productdata` is **class2**

Comment: Hi Romi, please take a look at my new question to understand the issue and can help: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009705/javascript-jquery-how-to-get-data-value-from-another-class] , Thank you so much